# .xml filenot found on intellij community edition

Tags: xml, spring, path, configuration, filenotfoundexception

error in intellij community edition: { java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist } ... But when I try to delete this file it says potentially unsafe to delete references found in code as shown in picture
my code is: ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
I have tried every single path possible like path from current root, path from source root but can't find the solution.[enter image description[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCTAj.png) here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zez0l.png)

tried every path possible, path from current root, path from source root but can't find the solution. everytime it gives filenotfound exception.

after making resource file
[updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFiHn.png)

[errors in updated(still no change)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcgM5.png)

[updated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw4XI.png)

Comment: `config.xml` needs to go in `src/main/resources` not in `src/main/java`./

Comment: there isn't any resources folder, should I create it manually in the directory, or intellij will provide me somehow?

Comment: If there isn't create it and move the file.

Comment: did that but no improvement... IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [src/main/resources/config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [src/main/resources/config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: The file path you are loading shouldn't include `src/main/resources`, which is part of your problem, also after adding that path, you need to refresh your maven project.

Answer (score 0):

I got this right by adding resource folder in this setting of project structure:

[image: settings in file -> project structure]